# really high resolutions become pixelated, as if the camera is zoomed in too much

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, zooming, unityscript, image-quality

I'm working on a Unity 2D project and making the levels at the moment.

For some reason even really high resolutions (higher than 1920x1080) become really pixelated. It's like the camera is zoomed in too much. My player is rendered at a scale of 0.2x0.2.

I've tried changing the z-depth of camera back but everything still becomes very pixelated. Really frustrating because edges of tiles on the screen become really pixelated.

Anyone had any issue or can think of anything that will help solve this?

here's a picture of it in the editor mode. Based on the tile grid you can see everything's really tiny and it's awfully zoomed in. Not sure how to fix this.

[image]

In game:

[image]

Noticed how pixelated it is. Thanks

Comment: Please check camera size maybe change it more than 5 is solution.

Answer (score 0):

On your first screenshot the sprites are also pixelated.

Every time you see bad image quality - checkout import settings. Try to increase max size. Also try different format. You should find the suitable values for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I find that when I set the export settings to Android, everything gets pixelated, even skies (I suppose it does that in order to adapt to the device's lower capacity). Turning export settings back to web player for example, solves this issue.

Comment: Not 'export' settings, but 'import'. Also, you can play with disable/enable override settings for specific platform.